# NumberFormatException in connecting Azure Service Bus using Managed Identity

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to Azure Service Bus from my webjob using Managed Identities. But unfortunately, I am getting the following error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10/10/2020 6:50:38 AM +00:00"
```

I have enabled Identity and assigned Contributor role for connecting to Service bus. Also, in the code, I have used ClientSettings to create a connection with Service bus.

```
ClientFactory.createMessageReceiverFromEntityPathAsync(namespace, queueName,new ClientSettings(TokenProvider.createManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider()), ReceiveMode.RECEIVEANDDELETE).get();
```

Any idea how to resolve this exception, as it is thrown from built-in class **ManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider**. Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT -**
I updated the service bus package to 3.2.0. Now I can't see NumberFormatException but I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect` even though I have provided the 'Owner' role to the webjob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect Azure Service bus with Azure  Managed Identity, we need to assign some special role(**Azure Service Bus Data Owner**, **Azure Service Bus Data Sender** and **Azure Service Bus Data Receiver** ) to the MSI. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#assigning-azure-roles-for-access-rights).

For example

1. Assing role to the MSI
2. Code

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        IMessageReceiver receiver = null;
        try {
             receiver= ClientFactory.createMessageReceiverFromEntityPathAsync("bowman1012",
                    "myqueue",
                     new ClientSettings(TokenProvider.createManagedIdentityTokenProvider()),
                     ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK).get();
            IMessage message = receiver.receiveAsync().get();
            String content = new String(message.getBody(), UTF_8);
            System.out.println(content);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
          Boolean f=  receiver.closeAsync().complete(null);
          System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the same piece of code, also I have assigned the desired roles for my service bus, still getting the same exception.

Comment: @Shreyanshi Is that you use the windows app service?

Comment: @Shreyanshi Could you please create a new web app to run webjob?

Comment: I tried creating a new app with windows and Java config, still the same issue. Could you please send your app service configuration